# Selenium with Python, script runs but nothing happens

Tags: python, selenium

So I'm starting a new testing build for a UI.

I can't figure out why my script is saying `[finished 0.6s]` but nothing is happening. The Chrome browser isn't opening or executing the tests:

I've places some `print("working")` in various parts of the code to see where it's stopping and it doesn't seem to run past the class statement. Here's the first part of the code.

```
import unittest
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

class UI(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe")
        self.driver.maximize_window()
```

Comment: did you ever init or called the class or some function inside the file? Seems like nothing gets executed. Try `UI.setUp()` at the end of the file

Comment: Yeah I took this direct from the selenium python doc and "amended" it to naming conventions I'd be using. https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/getting-started.html#using-selenium-to-write-tests

Copy and pasting their code runs so I don't understand why mine isn't,

Comment: Did a direct copy and just edited the text rather than typing it out. Seems to be working now.

Answer (score 0):

You're defining a class `UI` and a method `setUp`, the code in there will only be executed after creating an instance of the `UI` class and calling the `setUp` method.

I believe your code could be simplified to

```
import unittest
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Firefox("C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe")
driver.maximize_window()
```